# Jackson multiple different schema for serialization of nested fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I want to have several different schema when serializing with Jackson.
Suppose that I have the following classes:

```
public class Department {
      private Person head;
      private Person deputy;
      private List<Person> staff;
      // getters and setters
}

public class Person {
       private String name
       private int code;
      // getters and setters
}
```

Now, I want to have two different schema for `Department` class. The first one contains only `head` and `deputy` where `head` includes both `name` and `code`, but `deputy` has only `name`. The second schema should include all fields recursively.

Thus, we will have two different jsons. With the first schema:

```
{
    "head" : {
        "name" : "John",
        "code" : 123
     },
     "deputy" : { 
        "name" : "Jack"
     } 
}
```

, and with the second schema:

```
{
    "head" : {
        "name" : "John",
        "code" : 123
     },
     "deputy" : { 
        "name" : "Jack",
        "code" : "234"
     },
     "staff": [
        { 
            "name" : "Tom",
            "code" : "345"
         },
         { 
            "name" : "Matt",
            "code" : "456"
         },
     ]
}
```

**QUESTION:** How should I do it with Jackson?

**NOTE:** These classes are just examples. For this simple example, writing four different wrapper classes may be possible but think about a complex example with dozen of classes that each one has several fields. Using wrapper classes, we should generate a lot of boilerplate code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Although the @bigbounty solution is excellent and I think that `View`s, in  addition to specific `DTO`s, are the way to go in general, in this case it may not be applicable because, for the same class `Person` we actually need two different behaviors in the same view.

[`@JsonFilter`s](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/) can be used to solve the problem.

This `main` method computes the graph what you need:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    final PropertyFilter departmentFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
      @Override
      public void serializeAsField
        (Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
        throws Exception {
        if (include(writer)) {
          final String name = writer.getName();
          if (!name.equals("deputy") && !name.equals("staff")) {
            writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
            return;
          }

          if (name.equals("staff")) {
            return;
          }

          // Ideally it should not be muted.
          final Department department = (Department)pojo;
          final Person deputy = department.getDeputy();
          deputy.setCode(-1);

          writer.serializeAsField(department, jgen, provider);

        } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) { // since 2.3
          writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
        }
      }
      @Override
      protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
      }
      @Override
      protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    final PropertyFilter personFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {

      @Override
      public void serializeAsField
        (Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
        throws Exception {
        if (include(writer)) {
          if (!writer.getName().equals("code")) {
            writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
            return;
          }

          int code = ((Person) pojo).getCode();
          if (code >= 0) {
            writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
          }
        } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) { // since 2.3
          writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
        }
      }
      @Override
      protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
      }
      @Override
      protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    final Department department = new Department();
    final Person head = new Person("John", 123);
    final Person deputy = new Person("Jack", 234);
    final List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(new Person("Tom", 345), new Person("Matt", 456));
    department.setHead(head);
    department.setDeputy(deputy);
    department.setStaff(personList);

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    final FilterProvider schema1Filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
      .addFilter("deparmentFilter", departmentFilter)
      .addFilter("personFilter", personFilter)
      ;

    mapper.setFilterProvider(schema1Filters);

    final String withSchema1Filters = mapper.writeValueAsString(department);
    System.out.printf("Schema 1:\n%s\n", withSchema1Filters);

    // You must maintain the filters once the classes are annotated with @JsonFilter
    // We can use two no-op builtin filters
    final FilterProvider schema2Filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
      .addFilter("deparmentFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll())
      .addFilter("personFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll())
      ;

    mapper.setFilterProvider(schema2Filters);

    final String withSchema2Filters = mapper.writeValueAsString(department);
    System.out.printf("Schema 2:\n%s\n", withSchema2Filters);
  }
```

For this code to work, you must annotate the `Department` class with:

```java
@JsonFilter("deparmentFilter")
```

And the `Person` class with:

```java
@JsonFilter("personFilter")
```

As you can see, Jackson also provides several builtin filters.

This code is very coupled to the test classes that you proposed but it can be extended in ways that makes it more generic.

Please, take a look at [SimpleBeanPropertyFilter](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.java) for examples of how to create your own filter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature JsonViews in the Jackson library.

You need to have a class for the views

```
public class Views {

    public static class Normal{}

    public static class Extended extends Normal{}

}
```

Next you annotate the Department class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

import java.util.List;

public class Department {

    @JsonView(Views.Normal.class)
    private Person head;

    @JsonView(Views.Normal.class)
    private Person deputy;

    @JsonView(Views.Extended.class)
    private List<Person> staff;

    public Person getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void setHead(Person head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public Person getDeputy() {
        return deputy;
    }

    public void setDeputy(Person deputy) {
        this.deputy = deputy;
    }

    public List<Person> getStaff() {
        return staff;
    }

    public void setStaff(List<Person> staff) {
        this.staff = staff;
    }
}
```

Keep the Person class as it is

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int code;

    public Person(String name, int code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

In the main function, where you are serializing the object, you need to enable the corresponding views.

```
public class Main {


    static Department createDepartment(){
        Department department = new Department();
        Person head = new Person("John", 123);
        Person deputy = new Person("Jack", 234);
        List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(new Person("Tom", 345), new Person("Matt", 456));
        department.setHead(head);
        department.setDeputy(deputy);
        department.setStaff(personList);
        return department;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        Department department = createDepartment();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String normal = mapper.writerWithView(Views.Normal.class).writeValueAsString(department);
        String extended = mapper.writerWithView(Views.Extended.class).writeValueAsString(department);

        System.out.println("Normal View - " + normal);
        System.out.println("Extended View - " + extended);
   }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Normal View - {"head":{"name":"John","code":123},"deputy":{"name":"Jack","code":234}}
Extended View - {"head":{"name":"John","code":123},"deputy":{"name":"Jack","code":234},"staff":[{"name":"Tom","code":345},{"name":"Matt","code":456}]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am familiar with JsonViews. But I think that it cann't solve my problem. For example, your output is different from my intended json. Because your mapper always serialize `deputy` exactly the same in both schemas.  But I want to serialize it differently in each schema.

Comment: You need to create a different view. I mean class @vahidreza

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please explain more? Do you mean that I have to create different views for the `Person` class? If it is affirmative how should I annotate `deputy` in the `Department` class?

Comment: @bigbounty answer is right @vahidreza. @JsonView can accept an array of views. You can annotate ```deputy``` with, say ```@JsonView({Views.Normal.class, Views.WithoutCode.class})```. You must also annotate the ```Person``` class with the appropiate views to obtain the result expected.

Comment: @JoséCarlosCampanero, do you mean that `name` should be annotated by both Normal and WithoudCode, but `code` just by Normal?

Comment: Although initially I thought that the problem can be solved with ```Views```, in the end I concluded that it may not be possible given that, for the same ```Person``` class, we actually need two different behaviors in the same view, and I think that is not possible. I will post an alternative solution.